# Fitting a Gaussian, getting a straight line. Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, curve-fitting, gaussian

As my title suggests, I'm trying to fit a Gaussian to some data and I'm just getting a straight line. I've been looking at these other discussion [Gaussian fit for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19206332/gaussian-fit-for-python) and [Fitting a gaussian to a curve in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21106809/fitting-a-gaussian-to-a-curve-in-python) which seem to suggest basically the same thing. I can make the code in those discussions work fine for the data they provide, but it won't do it for my data.

My code looks like this:

```
import pylab as plb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy import asarray as ar,exp

y = y - y[0]    # to make it go to zero on both sides
x = range(len(y))

max_y = max(y)

n = len(y)
mean = sum(x*y)/n
sigma = np.sqrt(sum(y*(x-mean)**2)/n)
# Someone on a previous post seemed to think this needed to have the sqrt.
# Tried it without as well, made no difference. 

def gaus(x,a,x0,sigma):
    return a*exp(-(x-x0)**2/(2*sigma**2))

popt,pcov = curve_fit(gaus,x,y,p0=[max_y,mean,sigma])    
# It was suggested in one of the other posts I looked at to make the
# first element of p0 be the maximum value of y.
# I also tried it as 1, but that did not work either

plt.plot(x,y,'b:',label='data')
plt.plot(x,gaus(x,*popt),'r:',label='fit')
plt.legend()
plt.title('Fig. 3 - Fit for Time Constant')
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.ylabel('Voltage (V)')
plt.show()
```

The data I am trying to fit is as follows:

```
y = array([  6.95301373e+12,   9.62971320e+12,   1.32501876e+13,
     1.81150568e+13,   2.46111132e+13,   3.32321345e+13,
     4.45978682e+13,   5.94819771e+13,   7.88394616e+13,
     1.03837779e+14,   1.35888594e+14,   1.76677210e+14,
     2.28196006e+14,   2.92781632e+14,   3.73133045e+14,
     4.72340762e+14,   5.93892782e+14,   7.41632194e+14,
     9.19750269e+14,   1.13278296e+15,   1.38551838e+15,
     1.68291212e+15,   2.02996957e+15,   2.43161742e+15,
     2.89259207e+15,   3.41725793e+15,   4.00937676e+15,
     4.67187762e+15,   5.40667931e+15,   6.21440313e+15,
     7.09421973e+15,   8.04366842e+15,   9.05855930e+15,
     1.01328502e+16,   1.12585509e+16,   1.24257598e+16,
     1.36226443e+16,   1.48356404e+16,   1.60496345e+16,
     1.72482199e+16,   1.84140400e+16,   1.95291969e+16,
     2.05757166e+16,   2.15360187e+16,   2.23933053e+16,
     2.31320228e+16,   2.37385276e+16,   2.42009864e+16,
     2.45114362e+16,   2.46427484e+16,   2.45114362e+16,
     2.42009864e+16,   2.37385276e+16,   2.31320228e+16,
     2.23933053e+16,   2.15360187e+16,   2.05757166e+16,
     1.95291969e+16,   1.84140400e+16,   1.72482199e+16,
     1.60496345e+16,   1.48356404e+16,   1.36226443e+16,
     1.24257598e+16,   1.12585509e+16,   1.01328502e+16,
     9.05855930e+15,   8.04366842e+15,   7.09421973e+15,
     6.21440313e+15,   5.40667931e+15,   4.67187762e+15,
     4.00937676e+15,   3.41725793e+15,   2.89259207e+15,
     2.43161742e+15,   2.02996957e+15,   1.68291212e+15,
     1.38551838e+15,   1.13278296e+15,   9.19750269e+14,
     7.41632194e+14,   5.93892782e+14,   4.72340762e+14,
     3.73133045e+14,   2.92781632e+14,   2.28196006e+14,
     1.76677210e+14,   1.35888594e+14,   1.03837779e+14,
     7.88394616e+13,   5.94819771e+13,   4.45978682e+13,
     3.32321345e+13,   2.46111132e+13,   1.81150568e+13,
     1.32501876e+13,   9.62971320e+12,   6.95301373e+12,
     4.98705540e+12])
```

I would show you what it looks like, but apparently I don't have enough reputation points...

Anyone got any idea why it's not fitting properly?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: First of all, the histogram of `y` does not look Gaussian at all!

Comment: How so? When I plot it, it looks like a Gaussian to me.

Answer (score 1):

The importance of the initial guess, `p0` in `curve_fit`'s default argument list, cannot be stressed enough.

Notice that the [docstring](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) mentions that

> [`p0`] If None, then the initial values will all be 1

So if you do not supply it, it will use an initial guess of 1 for all parameters you're trying to optimize for.
The choice of `p0` affects the speed at which the underlying algorithm changes the guess vector `p0` (ref. the documentation of [least_squares](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html#scipy.optimize.least_squares)).

When you look at the data that you have, you'll notice that the maximum and the mean, `mu_0`, of the Gaussian-like dataset `y`, are
`2.4e16` and `49` respectively. With the peak value so large, the algorithm, would need to make drastic changes to its initial guess to reach that large value.

When you supply a good initial guess to the curve fitting algorithm, convergence is more likely to occur.

Using your data, you can supply a good initial guess for the `peak_value`, the `mean` and `sigma`, by writing them like this:

```
y = np.array([...])  # starting from the original dataset
x = np.arange(len(y))
peak_value = y.max()
mean = x[y.argmax()] # observation of the data shows that the peak is close to the center of the interval of the x-data
sigma = mean - np.where(y > peak_value * np.exp(-.5))[0][0] # when x is sigma in the gaussian model, the function evaluates to a*exp(-.5)
popt,pcov = curve_fit(gaus, x, y, p0=[peak_value, mean, sigma])
print(popt)  # prints: [  2.44402560e+16   4.90000000e+01   1.20588976e+01]
```

Note that in your code, for the mean you take `sum(x*y)/n` , which is strange, because this would modulate the gaussian by a polynome of degree 1 (it multiplies a gaussian with a monotonously increasing line of constant slope) before taking the mean. That will offset the mean value of `y` (in this case to the right). A similar remark can be made for your calculation of `sigma`.

Final remark: the histogram of `y` will not resemble a Gaussian, as `y` is already a Gaussian. The histogram will merely `bin` (count) values into different categories (answering the question "how many datapoints in `y` reach a value between `[a, b]`?").